# How to use 'disk from remote desktop connection' on Windows Server Core?

Tags: rdp, windows-server-2012, windows-server-core

When using Microsoft's Remote Desktop Connection, one can set certain local drives to be available on the remote machine.

On the remote box they show up in Explorer as 'E on LOCALBOX' and provide a simple way to copy files back and forth.

On Server Core installations there is no Explorer, so how can I access the drives from the command line?

When using third party file managers that run on Server Core, the drives show up as 'System Folder' but am I unable to open them.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

On the command line:

```
\\tsclient\c
```

Either use Powershell, or map the UNC to a drive letter.

[image]

Comment: I noticed myself that typing '\\tsclient\c' did work in xplorer2 but using cmd.exe did not. But you are right, it works in PowerShell and mapping it works as well (even though I'm sure I tried that before).

Answer (score 0):

To quickly map and use from the command prompt:

```
pushd \\tsclient\c
```

When you're done:

```
popd
```

Answer (score 0):

In Powershell, you should use:

```perl
Set-Location \\tsclient\directory
```

@eric-jarvi your answer helped me.  That worked like a charm and it works in Powershell and CMD!

The accepted answer does not work if you only map certain directories to share.